# Python: Storing value of self Variable

Tags: python, variables, updates, store, self

I've got a problem with storing my Variable `self.data_counter` in an other variable like `prev_counter_data`. 
I simply can't store the current value - the variable i assign `self.data_counter` to has always the exact same values somehow.

```
class SimpleSwitch(app_manager.RyuApp):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SimpleSwitch, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.data_counter = {}
        self.monitor_thread = hub.spawn(self._monitor)

    def _monitor(self):
        timer = 0
        prev_data_counter = self.data_counter
        while True:
            hub.sleep(5)
            timer = timer + 5
            # assign current values to self.data_counter in func()
            func()
            # compare current values to previous values

            if (timer%60) == 0:
                prev_data_counter = self.data_counter
```

Any idea where the flaw in my thinking is? Why is `prev_data_counter` always equal to `self.data_counter`?

The Dictionary `self.data_counter`contains information like [(id, port):traffic]. I can assign values via `self.data_counter[id][port] = traffic`.

Comment: `self.data_counter` is constantly being changed in the while loop. `prev_data_counter` should be updated every 60 seconds to match the values of `self.data_counter`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `self.prev_data_counter = self.data_counter` we are saying they are the same object.

Try:

`self.prev_data_counter  = copy.copy(self.data_counter)`

And add the copy package: `import copy`

See also:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html

Comment: Thank you! That might be a valid solution. Is there any way to assign the values without importing additional packages?

Comment: There is a dirty trick you can use if your variables are ints, which is summing and subtraction one from the variable, e.g. `a=1` then, `b=a+1`, then `b=b-1`. Then, note that `a` and `b` are different objects. In any case, it depends on the type of self.data_counter.

Comment: Using copy.copy() and copy.deepcopy() still me a KeyError, when trying to read the copied dictionary.
`self.data_counter[id][port]` works fine.
`prev_data_counter[id][port]` throws a key error for the port entry.

Comment: @JaboSammy, `copy.deepcopy()` worked fine here for a generic dictonary. What is the output of `dir(prev_data_counter[id])`?

Comment: Apparently the ID is also a KeyError.

Comment: What is the output of `dir(prev_data_counter)` then? Also, are you using deepcopy in both instances of `prev_data_counter = self.data_counter`? Finally, does `func()` uses `prev_data_counter`? something could be happening there.

Comment: EDIT: I believe i found the error. Let me look further into the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your data counter is dictionary. Dictionaries are mutable objects. When you asign self.data_counter to prev_data_counter you actually just save the reference to the same dictionary object. So when you update self.data_counter you update prev_data_counter too - they are referencing to the same object.

You need to create copy of your dictionary:

```
prev_data_counter = self.data_counter.copy()
```

Comment: Using this throws me a KeyError, when trying to read the copied dictionary. self.data_counter[id][port] works fine. prev_data_counter[id][port] throws a key error for the port entry.